# Sum of reciprocals of natural numbers with numerator being Legendre symbol mod 7 (L-series)

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

How do I show that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left({k \over 7}\right)\Big/k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{7k+1} + \frac{1}{7k+2} - \frac{1}{7k+3} + \frac{1}{7k+4} - \frac{1}{7k+5} - \frac{1}{7k+6}\right)$$ is  $\pi/\sqrt{7}$ (this is the result Mathematica gives)

I think this can be done by expressing it in terms of sums that look like the power series for log(1+x) but I am not sure how.

Comment: The topic to search for is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula#Dirichlet_class_number_formula ... your quantity is $L(1,\chi)$ where $\chi(n) = (\frac n7)$.